# server.xml changes being cleared when I restart tomcat from eclipse

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat6

When I restart/start Tomcat after changing files like server.xml, tomcat-users.xml
the changes disappear. It looks like the files always get back to their default.

I'm using Tomcat 6.

What can I do to make the changes stay?
Thanks!!

Comment: No that's not true may be you have miss something?tell me what you change??

Comment: for example I opend the /cong/tomcat-users.xml and removed the
comments from the user section

Comment: I have already did that but found no problem.I think you are something doing wrong

Comment: Maybe its somthing with my eclipse tomcat definitions..

Comment: download apache-tomcat latest version and configure it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make these changes in the `Servers` project, which Eclipse WTP copies of the Tomcat configuration files. They will be copied into the Tomcat instance you run from within Eclipse. (More details in the [WTP documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#When_I_create_my_first_Tomcat_server.2C_why_is_a_Servers_project_created_in_my_workspace.3F).)